# Trust Limit Issue

Tags: trustline

I am running my own stellar private network and have one account of this network. Issued one asset called "FOO" to this account which limit is 9999999999. After funding to this asset for few days, getting op_line_full error. Then I figured out the issue and got to know that trust limit needs to be changed. Here I am able to increase trust limit up to 99999999999. If I try to increase more than that then it will throw ArithmeticOverflowException. Any suggestion?

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: stellar sdk 0.8.0

Comment: which language is the SDK?

Comment: sdk language is java.